# Is there a system for creating visuals of characters?

Tags: system-agnostic, tool-recommendation, art

I'm thinking [something like this](http://www.daz3d.com/mech-gear-for-genesis-2-male-and-female-bundle), except for fantasy games like D&D or Pathfinder. Base models of various races (gnome, human, half-orc, whatever), each with compatible artwork of equipment.

It doesn't have to be like the link, just some means of keeping a character's appearance updated as they use different armor, weapons, etc. It doesn't have to be actually animated like a video game model, though the ability to change poses would be preferred.

After searching myself, I only find the wrong kind of fantasy stuff (aka bikinis) or very limited things (like three sword models but no axes, or axes but they aren't compatible with the same person model as the swords, etc). Anybody ever run across something that fits the bill?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many character creators for fantasy games in computer gaming.

The PC versions of many RPGs have extensive character creators. The Dragon Age series, and the World of Warcraft game have extensive customization options.

There is also the custom miniature creator HeroForge - https://www.heroforge.com/ which is designed to let you visualize your own characters in 3D. It is monochrome, because it's intended to create minis in a single color. You could use it to create a character and then color it in another program.

Then there are game creation tools, like the character creator for Unity3D. You'll need the free Unity engine as well as a [couple](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/13930) of [plugins](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/14833). This is meant for game creators, but does not require coding - it is meant to a) make characters and b) provide the kind of character creator the big games above have. For $25 you get a ton of options and parameter sliders - and you can [try it out for free](http://strafejumpstudios.com/umazing/). You'll probably have to use Firefox as Chrome no longer supports the old Mozilla plugin architecture.

These are all the result of lots of effort by professional designers and developers and are likely to yield suitable results.

Comment: Heroforge is pretty dang neat, but no coloring options. Unity3D looks sweet, but unfortunately it is also well outside my experience. Using a game's character creation, however, is a fantastic idea.

Comment: I blame NCSoft for the loss of the most awesome character designer ever. RIP City of Heroes.

Answer (score 5):

There is a free web-based tool called [Hero Machine](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=hero%20machine).  It has several versions -- modern, superhero, and fantasy, at least -- and does exactly what you're after.  Character images are stored as text strings that allow the Hero Machine to recreate the illustration when reloaded, though you can also use a screen dumper or print-to-file to save an actual image file.  I've used it quite a bit when I was playing more -- it's easy, fairly quick, and there are lots of variations available.  Unfortunately, you can't transfer pieces from one version to another, but that's a minor restriction.

Comment: This is great :)

Comment: I spent some time on it, and it works pretty well. However, the backgrounds are extremely limited, and I can't figure out how to make a character grip an item properly. Still, this is pretty good.

Comment: For backgrounds, you could just leave the background plain/transparent, and paste the screen dumped character illustraction onto your preferred background (haven't tried this, but it should work).  For grip, you may have to play with "move up" and "move down" to adjust which layer is where in relation to other layers.

Comment: The problem is the thumb; you can't put a weapon under part of the hand yet atop another part. So it never quite looks like the character is gripping it.

Comment: Ah.  I don't know that I've tried poses that show the thumb, but I last used Hero Machine for superhero games and most of those poses show the back of the hand, so the thumb/fingers layering is circumvented.  You might experiment with gloves or gauntlets.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind spending some money [Epic Generator](http://epicgenerator.net/) is a picture generator, it can be quite pricey as you have to buy packs depending on what sort of character you want, but the visuals are pretty impressive. I've used it for a few characters before I ran out of money ;)

Sample from their website:

[image]

Otherwise some of my players use "Doll generators" (Just google) of which there are dozens around online, these are just like the old fashioned stick-on-clothes to a picture sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

### Not Cheaply

There is a 2D character art program by [Profantasy Software](https://secure.profantasy.com), unimaginatively named "[Character Artist](https://secure.profantasy.com/products/ca.asp#&panel1-1)".  It's an addon for the Campaign Cartographer suit of tools.  It's rather a bit pricey though.  As of writing this answer, Campaign Cartographer is $45 US, and Character Artist is $40 US.

This has the advantage of being designed for fantasy role-play art, however that is currently a limitation of the software (it is not exactly suited for sci-fi games, for example, though some of the Annuals may have changed that).  Also, being based on CC3, it is CAD software more than anything else and has a bit of a learning curve.  On the upside, if you decide to go this route, it comes with a full fledged mapping suit suitable for role playing games.

Comment: Not cheap, no, but $85 is still cheaper than buying piecemeal stuff on a site like daz3d.com.

Answer (score 0):

I use the new version of epic generator. 
[image: example]